# Populate array compared to another array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have these 2 arrays

```
var array1 = [{
  id: "Test1",
  value: "Beep"
}, {
  id: "Test2",
  value: "Meep"
}, {
  id: "Test3",
  value: "Sheep"
}];

var array2 = [{
    id: "Test2"
  }, {
    id: "Test3"
  }],
  stuff2: [{
    id: "Test1"
  }, {
    id: "Test3"
  }],
  stuff3: [{
    id: "Test3"
  }];
```

I am looking for a way to insert empty objects or null to the 2nd array so that the 2nd array looks something like this:

```
var array2 = [null, {
    id: "Test2"
  }, {
    id: "Test3"
  }],
  stuff2: [{
    id: "Test1"
  }, null, {
    id: "Test3"
  }],
  stuff3: [
    null, null, {
      id: "Test3"
    }
  ];
```

This can't be ES6 since the code base I am working on it rather old (AngularJS 1.4).

I haven't been able to wrap my mind around this one. Any help is welcome.

Comment: Did you mean for array1 and array2 to actually be objects? As it stands right now, this throws syntax errors.

Comment: Also, are the objects in `stuff`, `stuff2`, etc. guaranteed to be sorted by id, or is that something the function would need to do as well?

Comment: `array2` is using `key: value` syntax in an array. That's not valid. Show what you're really trying to do.

Comment: So you want an array or object. What you mentioned as output is a malformed object.

Comment: I would argue that your data structure is not conducive to the operation you want to perform.

Comment: See if my solution is what you were looking for. Otherwise, we need more feedback

Comment: I have updated my question with the correct array. Apologies for the confusion.

Comment: The first array is the headers of a table and the 2nd array contains lines to populate the table. I would like to populate the 2nd array to match the columns (first array).

Answer (score 1):

I am making some assumptions about what you are actually trying to accomplish (based on your input and desired output). The idea is that for each key in the containing object (array as you called them), you check to see if the id of each element in the `stuff`, `stuff2`, etc. arrays is equal to the object's index in the array + 1. (i.e. `stuff[0].id === "Test1"`). If that is not the case, insert `null` into the array at that position and move forward. It would look like the following:

```js
var array2 = {
  stuff: [{
    id: "Test2"
  }, {
    id: "Test3"
  }],
  stuff2: [{
    id: "Test1"
  }, {
    id: "Test3"
  }],
  stuff3: [{
    id: "Test3"
  }]
};

function fillGaps(obj) {
    var keys = Object.keys(obj);
    keys.forEach(function (key) {
        var arr = obj[key];
        for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            var id = arr[i].id;
            if (id !== "Test" + (i+1)) {
                arr.splice(i, 0, null);
            }
        }
    });
    return obj;
}
console.log(fillGaps(array2));
```

Comment: You managed to figure out from my crappy English/newb programming skills what I wanted to achieve. Thanks so much!